# Set background image in aspx form

Tags: css, asp.net

I have to set background image for my home page and I have used this css code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url('/Images/emma-maersk.jpg');
    }
</style>
```

However, it is not working. Can anyone help me.

Comment: the url path is right still not working

Comment: Install FireBug and debug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting its `background-position` and `background-size`:

```
body {
    background-image: url('/Images/emma-maersk.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Check if the image exists. You can open Network tab in your browser's developer tools and check if this image is loaded properly.

Note that `/Images/emma-maersk.jpg` is **not a relative** path and means `yourdomain.com/Images/emma-maersk.jpg`. For relative path, you should use `url('./Images/emma-maersk.jpg')`.

Answer (score 0):

Also Add below lines in body{}

```
body{
background-size:cover;
background-position: 0 0 ;
}
```

And also Check Folder Spell and Case Sensitive.

Comment: still same result the image is in the Images folder of solution explorer is the path right?

Comment: Check folder letters is same. Like 'Images' and 'images' are different two folders

Answer (score 0):

For your addition, please make `background-size: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand method for setting background is

```
<style>
   body{
      background: url('Images/emma-maersk.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

use it in CSS3

```
 .backgroungImage {
   background: url('../imageS/background.jpg') no-repeat;
   background-size: 32px 32px;
   }
```

also add ".." before giving url if it exist in folder hierarchy.